# Bottom footer + Sticky nav bar

Tags: html, css

I've been trying quite many of css guides to put the footer at the bottom of the page and the example below is the one that I find the simplest.

```css
html,
body,
#root {
  height: 100%;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
}

section>div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <header>Header</header>
  <nav>Navigation</nav>
  <section>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
  </section>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

It is working fine in terms of putting the footer at the bottom of the page, but the nav bar actually fails to follow the scroll at some point.

I am pretty sure this is because I've set the height of #root element to 100%.

The problem is even if I could guess "why" this is happening, I ain't sure "how" to fix this and keep the element (nav) staying at the top of the page.

Any helps, please?

Comment: if the content-aware page height is greater than 100% and requires scrolling more than the `header` height, you will notice the `position: sticky` effect. I don't see a problem.

Comment: @AndreiFedorov Thank you for your reply! I ain't sure if I understood "content-aware page" properly, but I've actually added couple of `div`s with `height: 1000px;` to test and could confirm that the `nav` stops following the scroll after 100% :/

Comment: Thanks to @ths for adding code snippet to the initial thread.

Comment: What do you mean to achieve exactly? You want the sidebar to occupy 100% of the seen height? You want the navbar to occupy all the height between the header and the footer? You want the navbar to the top and not disappear? I am trying to understand what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @manjirosano basically, two things 1) `footer` stick to the bottom of the page no matter how long the `section` would be 2) sticky `nav` bar just like the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some javascript there to add a class `sticky` to the navbar when the window gets scrolled and when the scroll is not on the top. 
The class `sticky` contains some simple CSS like:

- `position: fixed` to make your div fix anywhere you want;
- `top: 0` to make it stick on top;
- `width: 100%` to occupy all the screen width.

```js
var navbarElement = document.getElementById("navbar");
var navbarScroll = navbarElement.offsetTop;

window.onscroll = function() {
  addClassOnScroll()
};

function addClassOnScroll() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= navbarScroll) {
    navbarElement.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbarElement.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#root {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  padding: 15px
}

nav {
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
}

section>div {
  height: 1000px;
}

footer {
  padding: 15px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <header>Header</header>
  <nav id="navbar">Navigation</nav>
  <section>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
  </section>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input bro! I actually wanted to solve this without javascript, but this should be the most valid answer for now XD

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost there. You just need to replace `height:100%;` with `min-height: 100vh;` for `#root`. And then apply `margin-top: auto;` to the footer element.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; /*Reset the default margin of the browser*/
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh; /*The default height should be 100% of view port*/
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto; /*Push the footer to the bottom*/
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <header>Header</header>
  <nav>Navigation</nav>
  <section>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
    <div>Test</div>
  </section>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input! Unfortunately, removing `height: 100%;` from `#root` will bring the `footer` up once I remove stylings for `section>div` :/

Comment: Ah now I can understand your problem. You can set `min-height: 100vh;` on `#root`, and put the footer to the bottom by `margin-top: auto;` @Pogeun

Comment: By the way, I updated my answer as well :D @Pogeun

Answer (score 0):

according to your HTML, you don't need to style the HTML and the body. just leave them alone. you just need to reset your CSS if you want.

You can easily achieve that without any javascript by making `#root` `fixed` with `100vh` and `100vw` and `overflow auto`. that's it.

```css
  * {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration-line: none;

    border: 1px dashed;
  }

  #root {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    background: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }

  section {
    flex: 1;
  }

  section>div {
    height: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <header>Header</header>
    <nav>Navigation</nav>
    <section>
      <div>Test</div>
      <div>Test</div>
      <div>Test</div>
    </section>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
```